# Closed Captioning Available

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #6: Is it really that [time] again?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/monthly-topic-challenge-6-is-it-really-that-time-again?cb=1).</sub>

---

*Please keep your arms and legs inside the space-time continuum at all times*

[ An old man becomes kind after seeing ghosts, 1843 ] (14)
[ An inventor uses a vehicle to get a nice story for dinner, 1895 ] (13)
[ A tailor learns a new language and gains telepathic abilities, 1950 ] (2)
[ A man and a cyborg try to meet a woman for different reasons, 1984 ] (1)
[ Two engineers create a box and stop being friends, 2004 ] (2)
[ A weatherman wakes up and tries to seduce his producer, 1993 ] (4)
[ A CIA operative fails an operation and gets recruited by another organization, 2020 ] (2)
[ A robot goes back in time to steal everything precious for scammers, 2007 ] (12)
[ A man goes on to fight aliens and meets a woman who does the same, 2014 ] (5)
[ A team of heroes foil the plans of an alien ruler, 2019 ] (14)
[ A teen takes a large course and unknowingly frees two prisoners, 1999 ] (20)
[ A teen drives a very fast car and meets his parents, 1985 ] (3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve this [time](/questions/tagged/time)-related puzzle, first we have to...

> ...identify the titles of movies and books involving **time travel** from their brief plot descriptions. These are as follows:
>
>  [ An old man becomes kind after seeing ghosts, 1843 ] (14) [**A CHRISTMAS CAROL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Carol) (Charles Dickens)
>
>  [ An inventor uses a vehicle to get a nice story for dinner, 1895 ] (13) [**THE TIME MACHINE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine) (H.G. Wells)
>
>  [ A tailor learns a new language and gains telepathic abilities, 1950 ] (2) [**PEBBLE IN THE SKY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebble_in_the_Sky) (Isaac Asimov)
>
>  [ A man and a cyborg try to meet a woman for different reasons, 1984 ] (1) [**THE TERMINATOR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminator) (movie)
>
>  [ Two engineers create a box and stop being friends, 2004 ] (2) [**PRIMER**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_(film)) (movie)
>
>  [ A weatherman wakes up and tries to seduce his producer, 1993 ] (4) [**GROUNDHOG DAY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day_(film)) (movie)
>
>  [ A CIA operative fails an operation and gets recruited by another organization, 2020 ] (2) [**TENET**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenet_(film)) (movie)
>
>  [ A robot goes back in time to steal everything precious for scammers, 2007 ] (12) [**BENDER’S BIG SCORE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama:_Bender%27s_Big_Score) (movie)
>
>  [ A man goes on to fight aliens and meets a woman who does the same, 2014 ] (5) [**EDGE OF TOMORROW**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_of_Tomorrow) (movie)
>
>  [ A team of heroes foil the plans of an alien ruler, 2019 ] (14) [**AVENGERS: ENDGAME**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Endgame) (movie)
>
>  [ A teen takes a large course and unknowingly frees two prisoners, 1999 ] (20) [**HARRY POTTER AND THE PRISONER OF AZKABAN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Prisoner_of_Azkaban) (J.K. Rowling)
>
>  [ A teen drives a very fast car and meets his parents, 1985 ] (3) [**BACK TO THE FUTURE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future) (movie)

Next look at the numbers in parentheses at the end of each clue.

> These are *not* letter counts. Instead they are indices, indicating a letter of the movie/book title that needs to be pulled out to help spell the final answer. Doing this yields the phrase **ONE TRUE COMIC**.

What does this mean?

> Well, 'One True Comic' is a [phrase](https://xkcd-time.fandom.com/wiki/One_True_Comic) referring to the xkcd web-comic instalment whose title is '[Time](https://xkcd.com/1190/)' - a comic that the OP of this question has listed as being one of their favourites in the description for this month's [challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/monthly-topic-challenge-6-is-it-really-that-time-again?cb=1)! The novelty behind this comic was that instead of being just a single still image, it actually consisted of 3101 stills, updating itself hourly over 4 months in 2013. It is held by many to be a masterpiece of web comic ingenuity.

Comment: I wanted to say I expected this to take longer, but then when I saw who solved it. Congrats to you !